# Show that the following sequence converges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Let $\gamma_n=(1+\frac12+...\frac1n)-\int_1^n\frac1tdt. \enspace$Show that the sequence$\{\gamma_n\}_1^n\enspace$ converges.

My approach is, if we can prove that the the above sequence is monotonic decreasing and bounded then we can say that the sequence converges.
$$\gamma_{n+1}-\gamma_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}\frac1i-\sum_{i=1}^n\frac1i+\int_1^{n}\frac1tdt-\int_1^{n+1}\frac1tdt$$
$$\implies \gamma_{n+1}-\gamma_n=\frac{1}{n+1}-\int_n^{n+1}\frac1tdt$$
Now for $t \in (n,n+1)\implies \enspace \frac{1}{1+n}<\frac1t<\frac1n \enspace \implies \frac{1}{1+n}<\int_n^{n+1}\frac1tdt<\frac1n$
$$\gamma_{n+1}-\gamma_n=\frac{1}{n+1}-\int_n^{n+1}\frac1tdt<0$$
$$\gamma_{n+1}<\gamma_n$$
This proves that $\gamma_n$ is monotonic decreasing sequence.
But I am stuck here. I am unable to prove that this sequence is bounded, which is required to prove that it is a converging sequence.
($\lim_{n\to \infty}\gamma _n \neq 0)$

Comment: The inequality that you used to prove monotonicity can be used in more than one way.

Comment: Draw a picture to see why the difference is always positive.  Then prove it.

Comment: @dxiv Thanks man. The suggestion helped me. I finally could prove it. :)

Comment: @sameedhussain Thought so, you were basically sitting on it ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f: [1,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) = 1/x,$ for all $x\geq 1,$ is a decreasing function, we have $$\dfrac{1}{n+1} \leq \dfrac{1}{x} \leq \dfrac{1}{n},$$ for all  $n \leq x\leq n+1.$ Hence, $$
\int^{n+1}_{n} \dfrac{1}{t}  dt \leq \dfrac{1}{n}.$$ Thus,
$$ \sum^{k}_{i=1}\int^{i+1}_{i} \dfrac{1}{t} dt \leq \sum^{k}_{i=1}\dfrac{1}{i}, 
$$ which implies that $$0\leq \sum^{k}_{i=1}\dfrac{1}{i} - \sum^{k}_{i=1}\int^{i+1}_{i} \dfrac{1}{t} dt  = \sum^{k}_{i=1}\dfrac{1}{i} - \int^{k+1}_{1} \dfrac{1}{t} dt \leq   \sum^{k}_{i=1}\dfrac{1}{i} - \int^{k}_{1} \dfrac{1}{t} dt =\gamma^{k}.$$ This means that $\{\gamma^k\}$ is a decreasing and bounded below by zero sequence, meaning it converges.

Comment: What is that $\gamma ^k$ in your proof.

Comment: Hoo! Sorry! $\gamma^k$ is the same of $\gamma_k.$ This is the $k-$th term of your sequence. This is because in multivariate calculus, the $k-$th term of a sequence is denoted by an index above the symbol, and not below

Comment: I see. Thanks for you contribution. Though I proved it. :)

Comment: What about the limit?

Comment: The limit can only be computed numerically. It's like $\pi$.